# Swift Unified Logging

Tags: swift, logging, oslog

I was searching for some information on how to do proper logging in swift. I found Unified Logging: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging.

When trying it, I couldn't figure out how I can see the logs for only my defined Subsystem and the Category. Is there a way in the console oder the system log of the ios simulator to have only the application related logs? I couldn't see the app logs neither in the console nor in the simulator's system logs.

Here is my code:

```
let customLogger = OSLog(subsystem: "com.myapp", category: "CustomLogs")
os_log("Test log message.", log: customLogger, type: .debug)
```

Comment: `.debug` never shows up. If you use `.info`, it will show up in both places

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509909/swift-oslog-os-log-not-showing-up-in-console-app

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In case you still looking for an answer.