# Swift: OSLog/os_log not showing up in console app

Tags: swift, logging

I am building a Swift 5 application with XCode 10.3. For this, I have a framework which contains a implementation for a logsystem (for debugging purposes). The default implementation for this logsystem is based on OSLog/os_log. When using the system in the consuming app, then none of the logs appear in the Console app. However, when placing breakpoints, I can see that the `os_log` statement (see code example below) is reached and that the correct parameters are passed on to the `os_log` function. However, when I use os_log or NSLog in the host application, then they do show up.

I have verified that it is not an issue with the `LogSystem` / `DefaultLogImplementation` types as all of the breakpoints that need to be hit, are hit, and all unit tests are green. In addition, the `os_log` statement is reached and executed, but the logs do not appear. I have verified that all messages are shown in the console app, I have verified that I have selected the correct device, I have tried multiple filters (and even dug through all the logs without filters enabled)...

Can anyone help / give a pointer at what the issue may be? I am currently suspecting that there is a bug in the implementation of OSLog/os_log.

**Code sample**

*App-side code, which consumes code similar to the examples provided below*

```
class SomeClass {
    private let logSystem = LogSystem()

    func doSomethingImportant() {
        // Do important stuff and log the result
        logSystem.debug("Finished process with result \(result)")
    }

}
```

*Framework-side code, which is consumed by the app*

```
public class LogSystem {

    private let logImplementation: LogImplementation

    init(_ logImplementation: LogImplementation = DefaultLogImplementation()) {
        self.logImplementation = logImplementation
    }

    public func debug(_ message: String) {
        logImplementation.log(message, type: .debug) // And some other parameters...
    }

    public func error(_ message: String) {
        // Similar to debug(:)...
    }

}

public protocol LogImplementation {
    func log(_ message: String, type: LogType, ...other parameters...)
}

public class DefaultLogImplementation: LogImplementation {
    func log(_ message: String, type: LogType, ...other parameters...) {
        let parsedType = parseLogType(type) // Function that parses LogType to OSLogType
        let log = OSLog(subsystem: "my.subsystem.domain", category: "myCategory")
        os_log("%{private}@", log: log, type: parsedType, message) // Breakpoint here is reached, but log does not appear in console app (even with debugger attached, which should remove the effect of "%{private}%". Either way, at the very least censored logs should still appear in console app.
    }
}
```

**Additional info**

Swift version: 5.0

XCode version: 10.3

Target device: iOS 12.2 iPhone X simulator

NSLog appears in console app: Yes

Selected correct device in console app: Yes

Correct filters: Yes

**Update 2019-08-16 13:00 (Amsterdam time)**

It appears that only .debug level messages are not appearing in the Console app. This bug occurs when using any simulator device in combination with OSLog. I have tried several commands to fix this:

`sudo log config --mode level:debug,persist:debug`

`sudo log config --subsystem my.reverse.domain.name --mode level:debug,persist:debug`

Neither of them fixed the issue. In fact, not a single debug-level message of the simulator is showing up in the console app (not even from iOS itself). Yes, the option to show .info and .debug level messages is enabled.

I tried setting the log-level for the simulator specifically through the following command:

`xcrun simctl spawn booted log config --mode level:debug`

But this result in an error:

`log: Simulator unable to set system mode`

Comment: Are you filtering on the right subsystem?

Comment: @matt definitely. I use a wrapper on top of os_log made by one of the frameworks, and when I use the wrapper then the logs from my own application dont show up either. (wrapper is written by myself as well).

Comment: Well then it sounds like the wrapper is at fault. But you have not shown it. You haven't shown _any_ code or given _any_ information as to how we might reproduce the problem you are having.

Comment: @matt I haven't shown it because I know the wrapper is not at fault. I breakpointed the crap out of it. I can see the wrapper function being called with all expected parameters, and I can see that os_log is also called correctly. But they don't appear in the debug console nor in the console app. In fact, when I copy the exact wrapper to my project it even works. I also verified that the framework the wrapper is in, doesn't disable logging or the wrapper. To me this seems like a bug in Swift or in the compiler, but I want to verify that I did not miss anything before making that assumption.

Comment: Well, unless you can provide _some_ sort of reproducible example, it's hard to "verify" anything and it isn't clear why you're asking this question at all. Just go ahead and assume away. :) If you think you've got a case for a bug report to Apple, file it.

Comment: @matt additional info that may help: I'm running xcode 10.3, using iPhone X 12.2 simulator, I have selected correct device in console app, tried filtering by subsystem, tried filtering by type, tried filtering my log message content all to no success. I will post a code example once I'm off the bus and behind a PC.

Comment: Oh one more thing to try: NSLog. If it works and OSLog doesn’t, that’s a strong case for a bug.

Comment: @matt NSLog works and shows up in console app. I have found other issues with OSLog as well. It takes any CVarArg as a parameter for the message string (it's a StaticString, the message string). The app some times crashes when passing on some types that conform to CVarArg as parameters for the format string.

Comment: @matt I have added a code example to clarify a bit more what I do.

Comment: Could the problem be that your OSLog object is a local variable? That's not how we're advised to do this.

Comment: @matt I tried verifying this by dumping all instantiated OSLogs in a static array to ensure that they will remain referenced and not cleaned up. This unfortunately did not work. I'm trying some other stuff as well now (making the OSLog itself a static variable)

Comment: @matt I have just tried setting the log-level to .fault by default and the logs then do appear. This is strange to me, as I have selected a settingin the Console app that info and debug-level messages should also appear... Investigating this a bit further

Comment: I tried sudo log config --subsystem com.test.testapp --mode level:debug,persist:debug which unfortinately does not solve the issue either... Only fault/erorr-level logs appear in console.

Answer (score 13):

In the console app, there are two options to include / hide debug and info messages:

[image]

Comment: Thx you saved me a lot of precious time!

Comment: Also - don't be surprised, if entries in Console app (when debugging app running on is running on phone) appears ~25-30 secs later than entries in log are recorded.

Comment: Thanks! Still the correct answer. Saved me from descending into console debugging madness.

Answer (score 7):

I've spoken with an Apple DTS Engineer and it's a know issues not being able to see debug messages using a simulator (in Xcode 11 too): open a feedback

Comment: I've been testing this in March 2021 and see exactly the same bugs with Xcode 12.5. Reported to Apple via FB9028830. https://twitter.com/steipete/status/1367424733113901059?s=21

Comment: I am using Monterey 12.6 and sometimes it works and sometimes not works for me, it's really interesting

Answer (score 0):

Please note that while debug messages may not work on simulators, they are fully functional on physical devices. It's important to keep this in mind when troubleshooting and testing your app.

- XCode - Version 14.3 (14E222b)
- Console App - Version 1.1 (8.1)