# Swift macOS App - Enable Info/Debug Logging in Apple Console App

Tags: swift, oslog

Implemented Apples unified logging system.

```swift
let logger = Logger(subsystem: "com.myapp.test", category: "someCategory")
```

**I am trying to make the logging visible in Apples Console App, but it does not work for Info/ Debug Levels.**

```swift
logger.info("Info Message") // not visible in Apple Console App

logger.error("Error Message") // visible in Apple Console App
```

In XCode it works just fine for all levels.

I have already configured logging for the subsystem:

```bash
sudo log config --mode "level:info" --subsystem com.myapp.test
sudo log config --status --subsystem com.myapp.test
Mode for 'com.myapp.test'  INFO PERSIST_OFF
```

What am i missing here?

<sup>macOS 12.4, XCode 13.3.1</sup>

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, but feel free to upvote the question, i will set a bounty if we get enough votes up.

Comment: Are `Console`> `Action` > `Include Info Messages and` and  `Include Debug Messages` enabled? Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66948803/979986?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem. Info and debug level messages must be activated in the Console application: `Console` > `Action` > `Include Info Messages` and `Include Debug Messages`.

Take a look at [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/console/customize-the-log-window-cnsl35710/1.1/mac/12.0) at Include info or debug messages.